# How to test integrity of user profile?

Tags: windows, corruption, user-profile

A customer of ours was having problems with our application. Eventually they let us know that their user profile was corrupted and creating a new user profile fixed the problem.

For future calls, I'm wondering if there is some way to validate the user profile integrity? Is there some sequence that we could add to our application startup to test for corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this and it may give you some insight as to whats really going on.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/10/20/mythical-creatures-corrupt-user-profiles.aspx

Comment: and more reading http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490855.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It only takes a couple of minutes to make a backup of a profile, delete it, and logon with a new profile to confirm if it is an issue with the profile or not.  I don't think you will find anything simpler or quicker.

Considering the long history Windows has with corrupted/hung/stuck/bent profiles, this should be a standard troubleshooting technique for any application team.

Comment: Any suggestions for on-the-fly testing of user profile integrity?